# Django Store HTML Input Array from _POST

Tags: python, html, django, json

So I am converting a site from PHP(Codeigniter) to Django, figured it would be a good way to learn. I can figure most issues out however I am stuck on this one.

In PHP i can `$e->estimate = json_encode($_POST['estimate']);`

to store an HTML input array as JSON encoded strings in the DB, does python/django offer any similar functionality.

I am looking at `simplejson.dumps(request.POST['estimate'])` but that throws a MultiValueDictKeyError

The POST contains items like `estimate[discount]
estimate[tax]

estimate[shipping]`

So can Django/Python do the above, take an HTML input array, JSON econde it and store it in the DB

Comment: Followup question, Changing fields like discount, tax, shipping are straight forward; however the form also has/capable of multiple line items (description, qty, cost) now using html array there isnt any real limit to how much I can store. Any suggestions to how I can resolve this new issue of having multiple line items in an HTML form and being able to store them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a look at the documentation in django I found that request.POST is an QueryDict object.

> class QueryDict
>
> In an HttpRequest object, the GET and POST attributes
> are instances of django.http.QueryDict. QueryDict is a dictionary-like
> class customized to deal with multiple values for the same key. This
> is necessary because some HTML form elements, notably , pass multiple values for the same key.

at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict .

As a dictionary (JSON object or Python dict) cannot have more than one key the JSON serialiser is throwing the MultiValueDictKeyError saying that you have multiple keys that are the same.

Not sure how php was doing it, but a fix would be either of the following

1. Copy the POST QueryDict and modify the contents so there isn't any duplicate keys.
2. Change the form data that is being submitted.

The reason for the QUeryDict is that for forms being submitted you might validly get multiple keys from the form, for multi-select fields etc.

hope that helps.

Mark

Comment: Thank you for the information, looks like I have to change the form data. Was hoping for a simple one liner like over in php :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem you've encountered is `MultiValueDictKeyError` which stands for there is no `estimate` key inside `MultiValueDict` `request.POST`. Try

```
# list existed keys
request.POST.keys()
# or
discount = request.POST.get('estimate[discount]')
tax = request.POST.get('estimate[tax]')
shipping = request.get('estimate[shipping]')
```

You could then construct something like

```
estimate = dict(discount=discount, tax=tax, shipping=shipping)
simplejson.dumps(estimate)
```

However, this is *not* [the normal way of process form in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/#forms).

Comment: The form data is variable with multiple line items done. Figure changing the form would be best